# Django humanize outside of template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, humanize

I know I can use the humanize module to convert date/time to a friendlier format in the django templates. I was wondering if I can convert those things outside the templates. For example in a `views.py` function or a `models.py` class(meaning outside of a django template). Is there any other library that can do that?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Yes you can

Lets say you want to call `naturalday` in `views.py` you would do

```
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import naturalday
natural_day = naturalday(value)
```

You can refer to the [source code here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/humanize/templatetags/humanize.py) for the signature, and options