# On the formatting of Python datetimes

Tags: python, django, datetime

A slight OCD question here - I'm using the {% humanize %} tag in Django which gives me date times returned in the following format:

June 17, 2017 07:24 pm

Now, within my post model in Django I am returning the following:

```
def published_date(self):
    """Returns a humanized date format for Algolia indexing."""
    humanized_published_date = str(self.publish.strftime("%B %d, %Y %I:%M%p"))
    return humanized_published_date
```

All works well. HOWEVER, the format returned in the above method is:

June 17, 2017 07:24PM

I've had a previous read of the datetime documentation here (https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) specifically the section "8.1.7. `strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior". I can see what I may need is the de_DE formatting - which displays a 12 hour clock suffix as pm and not PM.

So, my question is this. How do I re-format date times to give a format as the following: `June 17, 2017 07:24 pm`.* (As mentioned in the above code - I'm currently using `%B %d, %Y %I:%M%p`).

*N.B. I'm OCD to the point where I don't want June 17, 2017 07:24PM or even June 17, 2017 07:24pm! i.e., I need that space between the twelve hour clock and the ante meridiem and post meridiem suffixes.

Comment: According to the docs, the `naturalday` template tag in `humanize` - which is what I guess you are using - defaults to the value of the `DATE_FORMAT` setting if the date is not today/yesterday/tomorrow. Can you show the value of that setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a space and change the meridiem directive to caps:

```
...strftime("%B %d, %Y %I:%M %P")
```

The upper `%P` however is machine dependent; may not work everywhere.

OTOH, you may use the following hack to change the case of the last two characters. The `endswith` check ensures you're not breaking things in the datetime string and the right characters are replaced, otherwise, no replacement is done; might not satisfy your OCD:

```
d = datetime.now().strftime("%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p")
if d.endswith(('AM', 'PM')):
    d = d[:-2] + d[-2:].lower()
```

---

Final note, why aren't you using humanize directly in your model?

See [Django humanize outside of template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226779/django-humanize-outside-of-template)

Comment: Hi Moses. Thank you for your response. For me this just renders a "P" at the end of the formatted date...when you say machine dependent? I'm using Mac...

Comment: Would using a brute force method like humanized_published_date + ' am' or humanized_published_date + ' pm' work within some conditional statements?

Comment: Awesome - the hack worked. I guess for others the `%P` method may work. Certainly good to have both. One minor thing - I can accept this as an answer one there is a `:` after the `if`

Comment: To answer your question regarding humanizing within the model...I'm working with the Algolia search engine tool so I'm returning a format which I know will work with that.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to manually lowercase the value:

```
dt = self.publish.strftime("%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p")
humanized_published_date = datetime.now().strftime(dt[:-2] + dt[-2:].lower())
```

Here there's a complete explanation of this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38863210/how-to-make-pythons-datetime-object-show-am-and-pm-in-lowercase).
It depends on the C-lib implementation and the locale you are using, that's why there's no standard way of doing this.

But the Django DateFormat library seems to have more options in this regard: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/dateformat.py

This implementation should work as you expect:

```
from django.utils import dateformat

df = dateformat.DateFormat(self.publish) 
humanized_published_date = df.format("F j, Y H:i a")

print(humanized_published_date)
>>> June 21, 2017 09:19 a.m.
```

Comment: I just saw his message about being machine dependent, the other parts we were writing together.

Comment: Hi Daniel. Yes - certainly an acceptable answer. I've up-voted it - only reason why I went with Moses' answer is he pipped you to the post. :) Nonetheless, thank you.